# Wordpress monthly archive category specific

Tags: categories, archives

I have built a specific page to display only the posts in specific children categories. I want to have the monthly archive on the right hand side but only relating to those specific children categories.

So far I have this, however it is ignoring the child_of and displaying everything.

```
<?php $arc = array(
'type'            => 'monthly',
'limit'           => '',
'format'          => 'html', 
'before'          => '',
'after'           => '',
'show_post_count' => false,
'echo'            => 1,
'order'           => 'DESC',
'child_of' => 19);?>
<?php wp_get_archives( $arc ); ?>
```

And here is my page of code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-8">
        <h1 class="entry-title-big">Knowledge</h1>
        <?php
            $catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=knowledge' );
            while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
        ?>
            <article class="articlePost clearfix">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() && !is_single() ) : ?>
                <div class="entry-thumbnail col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));   ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="clearfix postDets">
                    <div class="the-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></div>
                    <div class="the-categories">
                        <?php                           
                            $categories = get_the_category();
                            $separator = ' ';
                            $output = '';
                            if($categories){
                            foreach($categories as $category) {
                            $output .= '<a class="feedcat" href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
                            }
                            echo trim($output, $separator);
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                    Read More...
                </a>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 
    </div>

    <aside id="serSideBar" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4">
        <div id="catsWidget">
            <h2>Categories</h2>
            <ul>
                <?php

                $args = array(
                  'orderby' => 'name',
                  'order' => 'ASC',
                  'child_of' => 19
                  );
                $categories = get_categories($args);
                  foreach($categories as $category) { 
                    echo '<li class="cat-item"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';
                    echo '('. $category->count . ')</li>';  } 
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="arcWidget">
            <?php $arc = array(
                'type'            => 'monthly',
                'limit'           => '',
                'format'          => 'html', 
                'before'          => '',
                'after'           => '',
                'show_post_count' => false,
                'echo'            => 1,
                'order'           => 'DESC',
                'child_of' => 19
            ); ?>           
            <?php wp_get_archives( $arc ); ?> 
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post ___all___ of the relevant code!

Comment: I have updated the code, which now shows how I am pulling in all of the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `child_of` argument for [`wp_get_archives()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives#Parameters). How, or why, did you expect that to work? You are attempting to use arguments that don't exist. That, I suppose, is the answer to the question. The function is ignoring `child_of` because the argument doesn't exist.

There are a number of filters in `wp_get_archives()` such as `getarchives_where` and `getarchives_join` that you should be able to use to achieve what you want, but the SQL is going to be complex.

But before running down that rabbit hole, what is the relationship to "wordpress's monthly archive widget"? Are you hacking Core? If so, the correct solution to this problem is most likely "create your own widget" and necessary code will be quite different.

Comment: Sorry thats because I took it from get_categories and was testing to see if it would work. I have had to build a specific page to display only posts from a collection of children categories. So I then I went the archive to work only for those categories also.